# Bootstrap accordion in my second div collapses but does not automatically close

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I wanted to use an accordion template I found. I have have several div elements where I want to put them in. For the first div element, everything works correctly, when collapsing the accordions, the other one's close again. However, for my second div element, the accordions open, but doe not close again (except manually by clicking again). Any idea what I do wrong?

This is my code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
                href="#accordionOne">
              Collapsible Accordion 1
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
               href="#accordionTwo">
              Collapsible Accordion 2
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Change does not roll in on the wheels of inevitability,
            but comes through continuous struggle.
            And so we must straighten our backs and work for
            our freedom. A man can't ride you unless your back is bent.
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
               href="#accordionThree">
              Collapsible Accordion 3
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>

        <div id="accordionThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
          You must take personal responsibility.
            You cannot change the circumstances,
            the seasons, or the wind, but you can change yourself.
            That is something you have charge of.
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
                href="#accordionFour">
              Collapsible Accordion 4
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
               href="#accordionFive">
              Collapsible Accordion 5
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionFive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Change does not roll in on the wheels of inevitability,
            but comes through continuous struggle.
            And so we must straighten our backs and work for
            our freedom. A man can't ride you unless your back is bent.
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
               href="#accordionSix">
              Collapsible Accordion 6
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>

        <div id="accordionSix" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
          You must take personal responsibility.
            You cannot change the circumstances,
            the seasons, or the wind, but you can change yourself.
            That is something you have charge of.
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You used the same `data-parent` ID for both accordions--change the second one to `#accordion2` or something, like `data-parent="#accordion2"` (and change the ID of the second accordion parent to match).

See [**this bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/CWglfaty0r) for the fixed functioning example.

Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Thank you for the tip, I tried it in my whole document, however it doesn'y seem to work, altough i followed your instructions, i see the bootply working. Is there something I did wrong?

Code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>ESLL FAQ</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Squad theme CSS -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="color/default.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">
    <!-- Preloader -->
    <div id="preloader" style="visibility: visible">
      <div id="load" style="visibility: visible"></div>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="visibility: visible">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse" style="visibility: visible">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                    <h1>ESLL FAQ</h1>
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#intro">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Fernwaerme Preisblatt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#service">Fernwaerme WDS Preisblatt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Anlage zum Kundenschreiben Preisänderung</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Section: intro -->
    <section id="intro" class="intro" style="visibility: visible">

        <div class="slogan">
            <h2>Willkommen bei der ESLL-FAQ</h2>
            <h4>Hier finden Sie Antworten auf häufig gestellte Fragen</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="page-scroll">
            <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /Section: intro -->

    <!-- Section: about -->
    <section id="about" class="home-section text-center" style="visibility: visible">
        <div class="heading-about">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" style="visibility: visible">
                    <div class="wow bounceInDown" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                    <div class="section-heading">
                    <h2>Fernwaerme Preisblatt</h2>
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>      
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /Section: about -->


    <!-- Section: services -->
    <section id="service" class="home-section text-center bg-gray" style="visibility: visible">

        <div class="heading-about">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" style="visibility: visible">
                    <div class="wow bounceInDown" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                    <div class="section-heading">
                    <h2>Fernwaerme WDS Preisblatt</h2>
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFive">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingSix">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSix">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /Section: services -->




    <!-- Section: contact -->
    <section id="contact" class="home-section text-center" style="visibility: visible">
        <div class="heading-contact">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" style="visibility: visible">
                    <div class="wow bounceInDown" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                    <div class="section-heading">
                    <h2>Anlage zum Kundenschreiben Preisänderung</h2>
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion3" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingSeven">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapseSeven" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseSeven">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSeven" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSeven">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingEight">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseEight" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseEight" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingEight">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingNine">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseNine" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseNine" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingNine">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>      

        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /Section: contact -->

    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">`enter code here`
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="visibility: visible">
                    <div class="wow shake" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                    <div class="page-scroll marginbot-30">
                        <a href="#intro" id="totop" class="btn btn-circle">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up animated"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>&copy;Tom Van der Veken</p>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Core JavaScript Files -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>

</body>`enter code here`

</html>
```

Comment: It is ficed! I had to change the parent ID in every accordion, not just the first one ;-) Thx for the support!